# Storing and iterating through stored values in C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, if-statement, input

In the function below the user inputs 10 numbers 5 stored in `X_users_inputs` and `Y_users_inputs`are being stored either in `X_users_inputs` if the `k` value is 0 or in  `Y_users_inputs` if `k` is 1. However the `if-else` statement is faulty I am trying to see all the stored values from both of the users. How could i fix the if statements down below.

Variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int input = 0, k = 0;
  char playerSelect[][2] = {"1", "2"};
  int X_users_inputs[10] = {0};
  int O_user_inputs[10] = {0};

  int s_count = 1;
  int l_count = 1;
```

Function

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
  {
    printf("\nPlayer %s input: ", playerSelect[k]);

    scanf("%d", &input);

    if(k== 0){
        X_users_inputs[i-1] = input;
        for(int l =0; l < l_count; l++){
                printf("X user %d\n",X_users_inputs[l]);}
        ++l_count;
        }
    else if(k== 1) {
        O_user_inputs[i-1] = input;
        for(int s =0; s < s_count; s++){
            printf("Y user %d\n",X_users_inputs[s]);}
        ++s_count;}

    k = ((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Player X input: 1
X user 1

Player O input: 2
Y user 1

Player X input: 3
X user 1
X user 0

Player O input: 4
Y user 1
Y user 0
```

Expected Output

```
Player X input: 1
X user 1

Player O input: 2
Y user 2

Player X input: 3
X user 1
X user 3

Player O input: 4
Y user 2
Y user 4
```

Comment: It seems that you are not comfortable with base 0, thats a problem in C

Comment: `((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1)` is equivalent to simply `i % 2` (as long as `i` is always positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `i` is being incremented between asking for `X` and `O` inputs. So the first `X` input goes into `X_users_input[0]`, then the first `O` input goes into `O_users_input[1]`. Then you store into `X_users_input[2]` and `O_users_input[3]`. As you can see, each array is skipping an element.

Instead, you can use `l_count` and `s_count` as the indexes into each array. Start them at `0` to avoid always having to subtract `1` to get the array index. I also suggest using better variable names -- if the players are `X` and `O`, use those consistently in all the variables.

Also, your main loop is executing 11 times, not 10.

```
int x_count = 0, y_count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("\nPlayer %s input: ", playerSelect[k]);

    scanf("%d", &input);

    if(k== 0){
        X_users_inputs[x_count++] = input;
        for(int l =0; l < x_count; l++){
            printf("X user %d\n",X_users_inputs[l]);}
    }
    else if(k== 1) {
        O_user_inputs[y_count++] = input;
        for(int s =0; s < y_count; s++){
            printf("Y user %d\n",X_users_inputs[s]);}
    }

    k = k == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: It works thank you, I fixed it but the `else if` statements print value should be `O_user_inputs` instead of `X_users_inputs`